# Getting specific digits in a binary number in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, binary

I need to be able to take the first 8 digits in a binary number, and save that value to a variable, then save the next 8, and so on. I read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators on bitwise operations, but didn't see anything about getting a specific digit or set of digits. I suppose I could just AND the number in question with another number that is all zeros except for the digits in question, which would be ones. For instance if the number in question was 10110011010111, and I wanted the first 5 digits, I could do 1000110011010111 & 0000000000011111 which would return 0000000000010111, which would be fine, but if there's a better or more direct way to do this, I would prefer that.

Edit:  I'm doing this to be able to store a number as a number in base 256, so I can use color to encode information. I don't need to know the actual ones and zeros in those locations, but what number they would be taken in groups of 8, and saving that number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splice`:

```js
var str = '10110011010111';
var arr = str.split('');

console.log(arr.splice(arr.length - 5, 5).join('')); // prints 10111
```